# CSS: Styled radio buttons not showing as selected

Tags: html, css

I have some custom radio buttons which are not showing as selected on click. The actual hidden radio buttons do get selected, but for some reason the styled color won't appear when I select the new ones. Can anyone lend some insight as to why?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dan5ermou5/f2aktvy4/1/

CSS:

```
  /*                                         /
 / CSS for A Place to Begin Section of Form /
/                                         */ 

    #apbContainer {  
        position            :relative;
        height              :702px;
        width               :233px;
        top                 :-320px;
        left                :274px;
        }

/* CSS for Text Boxes and Labels */

    label {  
        display             :inline-block;  
        cursor              :pointer;  
        font-family         :sans-serif;
        font-weight         :bold;
        font-size           :10pt;
        margin-bottom       :4px;
        position            :relative;   
        }


/* style radio button label */
    #radioapb label {
        font-family         :sans-serif;
        font-weight         :normal;
        font-style          :italic;
        font-size           :10pt;
        } 

  /*                      /
 / CSS for Radio Buttons /
/                      */

    /* remove old radio buttons */  

    input[type=radio] {
        display:none;
        }   

    .radio label:before {  
        content: "";   
        display: inline-block;
        width: 14px;  
        height: 14px;  
        margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;  
        position: absolute;  
        left: 115px;   
        bottom: 1px;  
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8); 
        border-radius: 20px;
        } 

     .radio label:before {  
        border-radius   :8px;  
        }

    .radio input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
        content     : "\2022";  
        color       : green;  
        font-size   : 14px;  
        text-align  : center;  
        line-height : 22px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- Client Check-in Form -->
<div id="apbContainer">
<form method="post" action="processcheck-in.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="formID" value="check-inform"/>

<!-- A Place to Begin Radio Buttons -->
<div class="radio">
<div id="radioapb">  
        <label for="male">Male</label>  
            <input id="male" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="m"><br></br>
        <label for="female">Female</label>  
            <input id="female" type="radio" name="GENDER" value="f"><br></br>

        <label for="yhomeless">Yes</label>  
            <input id="yhomeless" type="radio" name="HOMELESS" value="y"><br></br>          
        <label for="nhomeless">No</label>  
            <input id="nhomeless" type="radio" name="HOMELESS" value="n"><br></br>

        <label for="yveteran">Yes</label>  
            <input id="yveteran" type="radio" name="VETERAN" value="y"><br></br>          
        <label for="nveteran">No</label>
            <input id="nveteran" type="radio" name="VETERAN" value="n"><br></br>
</div>  
</div>
<input type="submit" name="dailyForm" value="Submit"/>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` is placed *after* your `label`, so `input:checked + label:before` won't work. The adjacent sibling selector (`+`) selects only the sibling ***right after*** the first selector. So place your `<input>`s before your `<label>`s.

I updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2aktvy4/3/

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `+` operator works on elements that come directly after the preceding element. If you change the order of your `<label>`s and `<input>`s, it will work fine.

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aarilight/x0kzz1cs/). =)

Also, a handy thing to bookmark is [this page](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048). It's important to learn what each of the CSS selectors are for. A similar one to the selector you're using is `~`, which will select any element that comes after the preceding element. For instance, if you had your `<br>`s in between a `<label>` and an `<input>`, it would still work.